# Regex to match all except URLs that contain specific directory?

Tags: regex, iis

I need a regular expression for IIS URL Rewrite that will process the rule only when the expression matches any bit of the URL EXCEPT a specific sub-root directory.

Example:

www.mysite.com/wordpress - process rule on any URL that starts with /wordpress after the domain name

www.mysite.com/inventory - do not process rule on any URL that starts with /inventory after the domain name

Tried `.*(?<!^\/inventory\/.*)` but it still matches the entire string.

Comment: if you have regex: www.mysite.com/wordpress , you want just this result: **www.mysite.com** ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a lookahead rather than lookbehind. Something like this I think:

```
^([^/]*/){1}(?!inventory\b)
```

Where you change 1 to 2 when the exclusion is needed at the next lower sublevel, etc.